# Retrieving table entries in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database

How do I pull the latest x amount of entries  from a mysql table and then display it in an html table, using PHP?

Comment: What language are you using on the backend and frontend? What have you  tried/researched already?

Comment: Amar, don't forget to **accept** the answers on previous questions that helped you. If you can't figure out how, try reading this section of the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: If you can edit your question to include specifics, such as the language you are using, please flag your question for moderator review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your table looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews {
    review_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY,
    titleofreview TEXT,
    yourreview TEXT,
    [...]
    created DATETIME
}
```

So when you retrieve the latest four reviews, it would probably use a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT titleofreview, yourreview 
FROM reviews 
ORDER BY review_id DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

If you only use a date to order them, then replace `review_id` with `created`.

As for putting it in a table, here is a [guide to making tables in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).